# how to deal with input type file when empty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Am kind of new to mvc and i am trying to upload a file using `<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />`. it is working when i attach a file to it via the browse button. but if i try saving the other form values when the file is empty, i get an error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I will be happy if someone can offer assistance.
here is a part of my code.

controller

```
public ActionResult InfoForm([Bind(Include = "Id, Title, Details, Day, Month, Year, Category, Status, ImageName ")] Info info, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Content\\images\\info\\" + file.FileName;
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    info.ImageName = fileName; // this line saves the name to the database.
                }


                db.Infoes.Add(info);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("InfoList");
            }
```

View

```
...
...
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(  model => model.Category, new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "UpComing Event", Value = "UpComing Event" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "What's New",  Value = "What's New"},

    }, new { @class = "form-control" } )

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Enable", Value = "True" },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Disable",  Value = "False"},

                }, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status)

<label class="control-label col-md-2"> Upload Image</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageName)
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

if there is no files selected then HttpPostedFileBase is null and you have used the statement

```
file.ContentLength
```

resulting as

```
null.ContentLength
```

you can figure out the rest

you need to check for null for file as

```
if(file!=null)
{ if(file.ContentLength>0)
...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. what i did was to check if(file == null){ save content} else { if(file.ContentLength>0){ save content and image }